# Make wkhtmltoimage Wait till Google Chart API Renders the Chart Completely

Tags: php, javascript

#### What I'm trying to do

Open a `.php` page using `exec` with

```
exec('./wkhtmltoimage-i386 abcdef.com/combined.php chart.jpg', $op, $er);
```

such that I get an image of the chart that was rendered.

#### What's actually happening

The `chart.jpg` isn't getting created at all on running the page which contains the above command.

#### Debugging

(1) I directly executed `combined.php` in a browser and the chart was being displayed as expected. So there is nothing wrong in `combined.php` code.

(2) I also tried putting just

```
<h1>Hello there!</h1>
```

inside `combined.php` and this resulted in `chart.jpg` being created and output shown up as image.

So this makes me believe that `wkhtmltoimage` will need to wait until the chart is being rendered and then perform the conversion operation. The thing is I'm out of ideas on how to make the conversion process wait till everything is done.

#### Javascript code used to prepare the chart

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);      
   var options = {
          title: 'TNS',titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}, hAxis: {title: "MONTH", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}}, vAxis: {title: "Percentage", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"},viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                 },
           max: 100,
           min: 0,
           legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
           },
           width:1000,
           height:550,
           pointSize: 8,
           backgroundColor:'#ddd9c3',
           is3D: 'true',
           height:550,
           vAxis: {
            gridlineColor: '#9d9983'
        },
            colors: ['black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']       
       };


       var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('tns1'));     
       chart.draw(data, options);

         }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following settings to allow JavaScript content to be rendered.

```
--enable-javascript
--javascript-delay
```

I'm assuming this documentation is up to date for that

http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html

An attempt could be

```
exec('./wkhtmltoimage-i386 --enable-javascript --javascript-delay 1000 abcdef.com/combined.php chart.jpg', $op, $er);
```

Depending on how long it takes to render everything off course. Keep in mind that different security restrictions might be in place.

Some additional options you will surely want to investigate

```
--run-script             // run a specific script after loading
--debug-javascript       // return javascript debug output
--no-stop-slow-scripts  
--enable-local-file-access
```

Comment: Hmm..So should the command look like `exec('./wkhtmltoimage-i386 --enable-javascript --javascript-delay 1000 abcdef.com/combined.php chart.jpg', $op, $er);` ?

Comment: The loading of chart doesn't take more than 2-3 seconds. Using the "attempt" code did not result in anything

Comment: Please define what exactly went wrong, did you get any output ? was an image generated ? add more info to your answer please.

Comment: Well, I explained everything I could in my question. Basically, when I use `combined.php` with google chart, image is not being created. If I directly run `combined.php` by typing it in the address bar, I see the chart on the browser, so this confirms that a chart is being rendered. To debug whether `wkhtmltoimage` is working or not, I replaced all code inside `combined.php` with `<h1>How are you</h1>` and this time an image was created.

Comment: Try to call wkhtmltoimage from the command line with the `--debug-javascript` parameters, do you see any output ? Are you loading any dynamic content ? ( setting script tags or ajax loads ? ) you can  verify if things get loaded with http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have SSH access so I can't run it through command line. And there is no dynamic content being loaded. Just data from mysql table. No ajax calls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30810/discussion-between-willem-dhaeseleer-and-asprin)